# Does Armadillo support boolean and 8-bit type matrices and cubes?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, armadillo

In the [arma docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube), I can only see cubes/mats having types `int`, `short`, `long`, etc. But not `uchar` or `bool`, which would be useful for storing images or masks.

Having a quick look at the [git repo](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/typedef_elem.hpp), I have seen the term `ARMA_U8_TYPE` but trying to initialize a cube via:

```
cube<ARMA_U8_TYPE> my_cube;
```

Or

```
cube<uchar> my_cube;
```

Lead to an error saying those types aren't part of the template.

Is there any way to initialize `uchar` or `bool` type matrices? E.g. tweak the `config.hpp` file?

P.S. I'm running C++11 on a 64-bit Linux machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm... there are already typedefs for uchar matrices

From

https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/typedef_mat.hpp

```
typedef Mat <unsigned char> uchar_mat;
typedef Col <unsigned char> uchar_vec;
typedef Col <unsigned char> uchar_colvec;
typedef Row <unsigned char> uchar_rowvec;
typedef Cube<unsigned char> uchar_cube;
```

UPDATE

And I don't believe boolean matrices (I mean packed ones, like std::vector) would be and could be supported, except when done with fully specialized code